# How do I get the complete string of a BLOB using PDO?

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I'm creating a C# to PHP Data Connector to allow for a standardized connection to a web server to host data from a database to a C# WinForm application. Everything is working with this one small exception.

The basic of use is this.

C# sends an AES encrypted command to the server. The server parses the command and performs the SQL query and returns an AES encrypted string. This string is then converted to a DataTable in C#.

When the SQL contains a column that is a BLOB I'm only getting back a small part of the full data. It seems that the field is being limited to only the first 2792 bytes.

Is there a setting that is preventing the full contents of the BLOB to be returned?

I'm not sure if it will be helpful, but here is the code that does the work.

```
$DataConnection = new PDO('mysql:host=10.10.100.102;dbname=jmadata', "root", "nbtis01");
$DataConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

if (isset($Parameters['SQLQuery'])) { // Default List
    $SQLQuery = $Parameters['SQLQuery'];
    unset($Parameters['SQLQuery']);
}

if (isset($Parameters['LimitOverride'])) {
    if (!strpos(strtoupper($SQLQuery), "LIMIT"))
        $SQLQuery = rtrim($SQLQuery, ';') . " LIMIT " . $Parameters['LimitOverride'];
    unset($Parameters['LimitOverride']);
}

$QueryParams = array();
foreach ($Parameters as $key => $value)
    if ($key !== '')
        $QueryParams[$key] = $value;

$Query = $DataConnection->prepare($SQLQuery);

$Query->execute($QueryParams);
$ReturnArray = $Query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if (!$ReturnArray)
    $ReturnArray[0] = array("NoResults" => "");
```

***EDIT*** -- ANSWER

I found my issue. The problem had nothing to do with PDO, PHP or MySQL. I was taking the BLOB data and doing a Base64 to it before putting it in the array, as the split characters I was using to build the result string that would be converted to datatable in c# used non-printable characters and the binary data as a string might have included these characters. The issue was when I was doing a convert in c# to get the original string so that could convert that to a byte array. I was using System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString to convert the Base64 byte array to the original string. This was working on everything but the binary data from the BLOB fields.

The suggestion that it might be a terminating character is what made me find it. Once the Base64 was converted to string using ASCII there was something that was turning into a terminator and it was stopping the convert at that point. Once I found this I changed to System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString and now it works perfect.

Posted the answer in case anyone else might be trying to do this and having this same issue.

Comment: Is it possible that a string terminating null character exists at that location?

Comment: @crush - I guess it could be possible. I'll test that and post/edit with what I find.

Answer (score 0):

More details in the Edit of the question.

Changed from System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString to System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString and the issue was resolved.

Thank you crush for pointing me in the right direction to find the solution.